# Handle URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, url-rewriting

I have a url like

"www.site.com/index.php/details/productname"

and I get 404 error on that link in codeigniter but the URL      www.site.com/index.php/details/      is working fine. I want handle url parameter in seo manner.

Comment: What is your question? CodeIgniter will be expecting `productname` to be a function in your `details` controller. What do you want to be different?

Comment: It sounds like you're doing: "function index($productname)" in the class details. Which you can't do. Is this correct? If so I can show you the correct code with/without use of routes

Comment: I want add a dynamic function name in details controller.
the main thing is that I want pass the only product name in url section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `/index/` segment in part of your url:
`http://www.site.com/index.php/details/index/productname/`

---

If you want to open url such like that `http://www.site.com/index.php/details/productname/`:

1) you need to define `_remap()` method:

```
public function _remap($method)
{
    if ($method == 'index')
    {
        $this->viewDetails($this->uri->segment(2));
    }
    else
    {
        $this->default_method();
    }
}
```

**OR**

2) use `application/config/routes.php` file

```
$route['details/(:any)'] = "products/viewDetails/$1";
```

---

From User-Guide:

1. [routers.php](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)
2. [_remap method](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html)

Comment: http://CodeIgniter/index.php/product/modular-adapter-db9-male-to-rj12-gray  is getting error but I want this type of output and on the product page how can I get the product link and fetch the data based on the productUrl which was after http://CodeIgniter/index.php/product

Comment: @user1161960 try `$this->uri->segment(someIntIndex)`